# FieldError at / Cannot resolve keyword 'title_icontains' into field. Choices are: complete, create, decription, id, title, user, user_id

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm getting an error while making the search functionality for my to-do list in Django.
[image: the error]

I was following dennis ivy's tutorial, did the same thing what he did but I'm still getting the error.
[image]

My code:

```
class TaskList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Task
    context_object_name = 'tasks'

    # For each user
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(user= self.request.user)
        context['count'] = context['tasks'].filter(complete = False).count()

        search_input = self.request.GET.get('search-area') or ''

        if search_input:
            context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(
                title_icontains = search_input)  # <= Here I get the error
        context['search_input'] = search_input
        return context
```

What is going wrong?

Comment: Instead of `title_icontains` it should be `title__icontains`, **two** underscores instead of one. In Django to separate lookups from field names, etc.  `__` (two underscores) are used. Here `title` is the field name and `icontains` is the lookup which is a case insensitive contains lookup.

Comment: thanks :). Ahh even the number of underscores matter don't they

Answer (score 1, accepted):

title_icontains acts like normal variable, whereas "__" double underscores are used for lookups, field relations etc.

```
context['tasks'] = context['tasks'].filter(
                title__icontains = search_input)
```

Please refer : [Making Queries- Django Doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/)

Comment: Thanks, :).  even underscores matter.